# Unhandled exception at ... Access violation reading location

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, background-subtraction

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\objdetect\objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i, M;
    Mat ycrcb, rgb, vect, Data;
    vector < String > files;
    /*Names of the pictures*/
    glob("C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\cubicle\\trainning\\*.jpg", files); // M=number of training images

    M = files.size();
// calculatong of the matrix Data
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {

// Lecture of RGB image

        rgb = imread(files[i]);
        namedWindow("RGB image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        imshow("RGB image", rgb);
        waitKey(10);
        if (i == 0)
        { //for the first iteration
            Mat Data(M, rgb.cols * rgb.rows * 6, CV_32FC1); //statement and allocation of matrix Data
        }
        rgb.convertTo(rgb, CV_32FC3, 1.0 / 255.0);

// Convert to float // Convert the RGB color space to the color space Ycrcbb*/

        cvtColor(rgb, ycrcb, CV_BGR2YCrCb);
        //making each image a vector line

        rgb = rgb.reshape(1, rgb.total() * 3);
        ycrcb = ycrcb.reshape(1, ycrcb.total() * 3);
        /*Concatenate rgb and ycrcb*/

        hconcat(rgb, ycrcb, vect);
        fprintf(stdout,
                "rgb=[%d,%d] , ycrcb=[%d,%d], vect=[%d,%d\n",
                rgb.rows,
                rgb.cols,
                ycrcb.rows,
                ycrcb.cols,
                vect.rows,
                vect.cols);
        vect.copyTo(Data.row(i));
    }

    int nclusters = 35;
    Mat labels, centers(nclusters, Data.cols, CV_32FC1);
    /* clustering Data by kmeans*/

    kmeans(Data,
           nclusters,
           labels,
           TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 0.65, 200),
           3,

           KMEANS_PP_CENTERS,
           centers);

}
```

This is the full code and I'm getting errors :

> Unhandled exception at 0x00b85c10 in PB.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xc35de59f.

[image: this is the code]

Comment: I would start by enabling break on access violation in the Exceptions item of the Debug Menu then walk up the callstack to the line of your code causing the problem. Also you probably should check if the images are successfully loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing of OpenCV, but this looks questionable:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i, M;
    Mat ycrcb, rgb, vect, Data;
```

Just defined variable `Data` of type `Mat`. Perfectly reasonable thing to do, unfortunately

```
        if (i == 0)
        { //for the first iteration
            Mat Data(M, rgb.cols * rgb.rows * 6, CV_32FC1); //statement and allocation of matrix Data
        }
```

made a second `Mat Data` that hides the earlier one and only exists inside the bounds of the body of the `if`. All the work done setting up this `Data` is thrown away at the closing curly brace when the inner `Data` goes out of scope. Outside of the `if` body the original `Data` is still active and accessible, but has never been properly initialized. Uses of it are somewhat questionable, so when

```
vect.copyTo(Data.row(i));
```

is reached, `Data` likely has no row into which `vect` can be copied. The subsequent uses of `Data` are equally questionable and any one could be causing the seg fault.

My suggestion is to hold off on the creation of `Data` until after all data is available.

Since you have a very simple function, changing

```
Mat ycrcb, rgb, vect, Data;
```

to

```
Mat ycrcb, rgb, vect;
```

and replacing

```
    if (i == 0)
    { //for the first iteration
        Mat Data(M, rgb.cols * rgb.rows * 6, CV_32FC1); //statement and allocation of matrix Data
     }
```

with

```
    static Mat Data(M, rgb.cols * rgb.rows * 6, CV_32FC1);
```

may be what you need.

[Read up on Static local variables here.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)

## EDIT

`static` local variables are a bit weird. They are "sorta" global. Their lifespan runs from first use to program termination, but are only visible inside the scope that defines them.

If defined in a function that will be called multiple times, the `static` variable will be allocated and initialized once. Not once per call. Subsequent entrance into the variable's scope will start with whatever the last entrance left, exactly what is required in this case. But for a larger program calling a function multiple times, this solution needs to be used with caution.

Comment: yes thanks, it was helpfull but i if data is not a global variable
it's now unknown for the fuctions :  vect.copyTo(Data.row(i)) and Kmeans.